# HDMI adapter not working

Tags: linux, usb, hdmi, arch-linux

I was perusing the internet a couple of months ago with the goal of finding a suitable device that would allow me to connect a third display to my laptop. I came accros an Arch user who suggested that the Hoco hub works best for Arch & Arch based distros.
I procured it online, it arrived and I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is some info regarding my system.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:244c Syntek Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 061: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 059: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 4-Port hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 058: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

mhwd -lh -d --usb:

```
02: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-2:1.0
Hardware Class: hub
Model: "Super Top 4-Port hub"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x14cd "Super Top"
Device: usb 0x8601 "4-Port hub"
Driver: "hub"
Driver Modules: "usbcore"
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v14CDp8601d0000dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00"
Attached to: #7 (Hub)

03: USB 00.0: 11500 Bluetooth Device
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-14:1.0
Hardware Class: bluetooth
Model: "Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x8087 "Intel Corp."
Device: usb 0x0aaa "Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)"
Revision: "0.02"
Driver: "btusb"
Driver Modules: "btusb"
Speed: 12 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v8087p0AAAd0002dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00"
Attached to: #7 (Hub)

04: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-6:1.0
Hardware Class: unknown
Model: "Syntek Integrated Camera"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x174f "Syntek"
Device: usb 0x244c "Integrated Camera"
Revision: "0.13"
Serial ID: "0001"
Driver: "uvcvideo"
Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
Device File: /dev/input/event10
Device Files: /dev/input/event10, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Generic_Integrated_Camera_0001-event-if00, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:6:1.0-event
Device Number: char 13:74
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v174Fp244Cd0013dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
Attached to: #7 (Hub)

05: USB 00.1: 10503 USB Mouse
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1
SysFS BusID: 1-1:1.1
Hardware Class: mouse
Model: "Logitech Unifying Receiver"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x046d "Logitech, Inc."
Device: usb 0xc534 "Unifying Receiver"
Revision: "29.01"
Compatible to: int 0x0200 0x0001 "Generic USB Mouse"
Driver: "usbhid"
Driver Modules: "usbhid"
Speed: 12 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v046DpC534d2901dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in01"
Driver Info #0:
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
Attached to: #7 (Hub)

06: USB 00.0: 10800 Keyboard
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-2.4:1.0
Hardware Class: keyboard
Model: "Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x413c "Dell Computer Corp."
Device: usb 0x2113 "KB216 Wired Keyboard"
Revision: "1.08"
Driver: "usbhid"
Driver Modules: "usbhid"
Device File: /dev/input/event3
Device Files: /dev/input/event3, /dev/input/by-id/usb-413c_Dell_KB216_Wired_Keyboard-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2.4:1.0-event-kbd
Device Number: char 13:67
Speed: 1.5 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v413Cp2113d0108dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00"
Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
Attached to: #2 (Hub)

07: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-0:1.0
Hardware Class: hub
Model: "Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
Device: usb 0x0002 "2.0 root hub"
Revision: "6.01"
Serial ID: "0000:00:14.0"
Driver: "hub"
Driver Modules: "usbcore"
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0002d0601dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00"

10: USB 00.1: 0000 Unclassified device
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.1
SysFS BusID: 1-2.4:1.1
Hardware Class: unknown
Model: "Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x413c "Dell Computer Corp."
Device: usb 0x2113 "KB216 Wired Keyboard"
Revision: "1.08"
Driver: "usbhid"
Driver Modules: "usbhid"
Device File: /dev/input/event5
Device Number: char 13:69
Speed: 1.5 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v413Cp2113d0108dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in01"
Attached to: #2 (Hub)

11: USB 00.0: 10800 Keyboard
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-1:1.0
Hardware Class: keyboard
Model: "Logitech Unifying Receiver"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x046d "Logitech, Inc."
Device: usb 0xc534 "Unifying Receiver"
Revision: "29.01"
Driver: "usbhid"
Driver Modules: "usbhid"
Speed: 12 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v046DpC534d2901dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00"
Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
Attached to: #7 (Hub)

12: USB 00.0: 0200 Ethernet controller
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-2.2:1.0
Hardware Class: network
Model: "Realtek RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x0bda "Realtek Semiconductor Corp."
Device: usb 0x8152 "RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter"
Revision: "20.00"
Serial ID: "00E04C360355"
Driver: "r8152"
Driver Modules: "r8152"
Device File: enp0s20f0u2u2
Speed: 480 Mbps
HW Address: 00:e0:4c:36:03:55
Permanent HW Address: 00:e0:4c:36:03:55
Link detected: no
Module Alias: "usb:v0BDAp8152d2000dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFip00in00"
Attached to: #2 (Hub)

13: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
SysFS BusID: 2-0:1.0
Hardware Class: hub
Model: "Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
Device: usb 0x0003 "3.0 root hub"
Revision: "6.01"
Serial ID: "0000:00:14.0"
Driver: "hub"
Driver Modules: "usbcore"
Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0003d0601dc09dsc00dp03ic09isc00ip00in00"
```

inxi -Fazy:

```
System:
Kernel: 6.1.26-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.1
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1-x86_64
    root=UUID=d8a426d2-b461-4915-9000-bcf28b90aee8 rw nouveau.modset=0 quiet
    splash apparmor=1 security=apparmor
    resume=UUID=c8cbc6ff-aee7-480b-94d0-fefc3b9dec30 udev.log_priority=3
Desktop: GNOME v: 43.5 tk: GTK v: 3.24.37 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM v: 43.0
    Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux
Machine:
Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81Y4 v: IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IMH05
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 v: IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IMH05
    serial: <superuser required>
Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: NO DPK serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: LENOVO v: EGCN29WW date: 09/03/2020
Battery:
ID-1: BAT0 charge: 38.9 Wh (100.0%) condition: 38.9/45.0 Wh (86.4%)
    volts: 12.8 min: 11.4 model: SMP L19M3PF7 type: Li-poly serial: <filter>
    status: full cycles: 249
CPU:
Info: model: Intel Core i7-10750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Comet Lake
    gen: core 10 level: v3 note: check built: 2020 process: Intel 14nm family: 6
    model-id: 0xA5 (165) stepping: 2 microcode: 0xF4
Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 6 tpc: 2 threads: 12 smt: enabled cache:
    L1: 384 KiB desc: d-6x32 KiB; i-6x32 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB desc: 6x256 KiB
    L3: 12 MiB desc: 1x12 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 3659 high: 4513 min/max: 800/5000 scaling:
    driver: intel_pstate governor: powersave cores: 1: 4246 2: 4466 3: 4513
    4: 4505 5: 4473 6: 4509 7: 4205 8: 2600 9: 2600 10: 2600 11: 2600 12: 2600
    bogomips: 62431
Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Vulnerabilities:
Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled
Type: l1tf status: Not affected
Type: mds status: Not affected
Type: meltdown status: Not affected
Type: mmio_stale_data mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Type: retbleed mitigation: Enhanced IBRS
Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via
    prctl
Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
    sanitization
Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Enhanced IBRS, IBPB: conditional, RSB
    filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: SW sequence
Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode
Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Lenovo driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 process: Intel 14nm built: 2016-20 ports:
    active: eDP-1 empty: none bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9bc4 class-ID: 0300
Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: nvidia v: 530.41.03 non-free: 530.xx+ status: current (as of 2023-05)
    arch: Turing code: TUxxx process: TSMC 12nm FF built: 2018-22 pcie: gen: 1
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 link-max: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s ports:
    active: none off: HDMI-A-1 empty: eDP-2 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1f95
    class-ID: 0300
Device-3: Syntek Integrated Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 1-6:4 chip-ID: 174f:244c
    class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 23.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting,nvidia dri: iris
    gpu: i915,nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch display-ID: :1 screens: 1
Screen-1: 0 s-res: 5360x1440 s-size: <missing: xdpyinfo>
Monitor-1: HDMI-A-1 mapped: HDMI-0 note: disabled pos: primary,top-left
    model: HDMI1 serial: <filter> built: 2020 res: 3440x1440 dpi: 146 gamma: 1.2
    size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23") diag: 869mm (34.2") modes: max: 3440x1440
    min: 640x480
Monitor-2: eDP-1 mapped: eDP-1-1 pos: bottom-r model: LG Display 0x05e5
    built: 2018 res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 142 gamma: 1.2
    size: 344x194mm (13.54x7.64") diag: 395mm (15.5") ratio: 16:9
    modes: 1920x1080
API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 530.41.03 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
    Ti/PCIe/SSE2 direct-render: Yes
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:06c8 class-ID: 0403
Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s
    lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10fa class-ID: 0403
API: ALSA v: k6.1.26-1-MANJARO status: kernel-api with: aoss
    type: oss-emulator tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
Server-1: JACK v: 1.9.22 status: off tools: N/A
Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.70 status: off tools: pw-cli
Server-3: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active with: pulseaudio-alsa
    type: plugin tools: pacat,pactl
Network:
Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:06f0 class-ID: 0280
IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    port: 3000 bus-ID: 0c:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
IF: enp12s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Device-3: Realtek RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter driver: r8152 type: USB
    rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 1-2.2:60
    chip-ID: 0bda:8152 class-ID: 0000 serial: <filter>
IF: enp0s20f0u2u2 state: down mac: <filter>
IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP) driver: btusb v: 0.8
    type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 1.1 bus-ID: 1-14:6
    chip-ID: 8087:0aaa class-ID: e001
Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down bt-service: enabled,running
    rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes address: see --recommends
Drives:
Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 74.07 GiB (15.5%)
SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends
ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: SK Hynix
    model: HFM512GDHTNI-87A0B size: 476.94 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B
    logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter>
    fw-rev: 11010C00 temp: 37.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
ID-1: / raw-size: 459.6 GiB size: 451.32 GiB (98.20%) used: 73.92 GiB (16.4%)
    fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 maj-min: 259:2
ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 300 MiB size: 299.4 MiB (99.80%)
    used: 312 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 maj-min: 259:1
Swap:
Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 17.04 GiB used: 145.6 MiB (0.8%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3 maj-min: 259:3
Sensors:
System Temperatures: cpu: 74.0 C pch: 54.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 53 C
Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
Processes: 370 Uptime: 11d 4h 20m wakeups: 64588 Memory: available: 15.49 GiB
used: 8.12 GiB (52.4%) Init: systemd v: 252 default: graphical
tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 12.2.1 clang: 15.0.7 Packages: 1442
pm: pacman pkgs: 1430 libs: 394 tools: gnome-software,pamac,yay pm: flatpak
pkgs: 12 Shell: Zsh v: 5.9 running-in: konsole inxi: 3.3.27
```

Do let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I'm no expert at deciphering that data, but nowhere do I see anything higher than USB 3.0 [& in fact a speed of 480 Mbps would make it only USB 2.0] or any mention of USB-C with Alt Mode… nor any mention of it supporting a 3rd display. https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_Gaming_3_15IMH05/IdeaPad_Gaming_3_15IMH05_Spec.html has no mention of a 3rd dislay either.

Comment: @Tetsujin So my machine will not support a 3rd display via USB to HDMI convertor?

Comment: What “Hoco hub”? There’s dozens of models.

Comment: Does your manual say it would support such a converter? Most of them would explicitly mention being able to use such an adaptor, and even then they would indicate which specific port needs to be used. Even then unless the laptop manual explicitly states three displays will work at once then its no guarantee, most would only do two displays unless you get some kind of [displaylink](https://www.amazon.co.uk/displaylink/s?k=displaylink) adaptor which is essentially a USB graphics card. Note that Displaylink adaptors can be slower than built in graphics.

Comment: @Mokubai But on the same laptop, on windows it recognizes the port so it shouldn't be a hardware limitation. I was hoping to find something along the line of an open source driver developed for USB hubs but there isn't any that will work with my hub. As for Daniel's question, I have a HOCO 4 in 1 hub with 1 USB C, 1 Ethernet, 1 Usb and 1 HDMI.

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski that it works on one OS and not another is important information that should have been in your question to begin with. We are not mind readers and takes us from "we have no idea if your computer even supports it" to "why isn't it working with Linux". You can [edit] your question to provide more useful details, such as also including the exact model of device you bought, "4 in 1 hub" could be an entire product line of different port configurations.

Comment: Here's something that may explain the different results: The Intel+Nvidia graphics. In Windows it seamlessly toggles cards on-demand, by software or by detecting external monitors. In Linux, OTOH, it depends on Kernel+drivers (Nvidia) and settings but typically the dGPU must be explicitly enabled (and you need to be running with dGPU in order to enable external video output). So, first of all, open Nvidia X Sever settings, select the Nvidia profile and reboot. Update/[edit] the question will ALL info.

Comment: @Mokubai You are absolutely correct, I should have provided more details about the product model and the fact that it works on other operating systems. I will update my question accordingly.